# Using Navigation Bar Activity on different Activities with each Activity's content

Tags: android, navigation, drawerlayout, setcontentview

I am trying to extend other activities into Navigation Bar Activity, I want to use content of the Activity with Navigation Drawer, but when I use setcontentView, Navigation Bar does not work.

This is my Navigation Bar Activity :
 :

```
public class navigationdrawer extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigationdrawer);



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer,  R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigationdrawer, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_dashboard) {
        Intent i = new Intent(navigationdrawer.this, dashboard.class);
        startActivity(i);
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_community) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_recipes) {
        Intent i = new Intent(navigationdrawer.this, Recipe.class);
        startActivity(i);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_leaderboard) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_upload) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_mypics) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_myvideos) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_contactus) {

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

This is my Second Activity :

```
public class Recipe extends navigationdrawer{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(new View(this));

//        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


}



}
```

I have commented setcontentview statement as I know that setcontentview is getting called in the Navigation Drawer Activity but I want Navigation Drawer and the content both. How to achieve this task?

Comment: You extend your new activity, but you **override** the changed method.

Comment: Do you mean, if you use navigationdrawer directly, it works?

Comment: Yes if i extend Second Activity and use super statement it does work, but it won't let me include the content of the second activity, as setcontentview is already used in navigationdrawer, so if i extend second activity into navigationdrawer activity, i am not able to use setcontentview. How to get content after extending?

Answer (score 0):

Use fragment instead of activities
Fragment is an part of activity. so, if you want to use singledrawer throughout the app then it is better to use fragment inside your navigationbar activity

note :
use fragment view inside your navigation drawer activity
like

```
if (id == R.id.nav_dashboard) {
    // write code for fragment replacement
}
```

Comment: Please understand my question properly, before answering.